# Dynamic/Static CPU Frequency Scaling

Tags: linux, windows, cpu, cpu-speed, cpufreq

I need to manipulate frequency of each core in my Intel i7 processor. There is a way to do it in Debian with the Linux kernel cpufreq subsystem. It is described in their [wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/HowTo/CpuFrequencyScaling).

However, I want to do it on Fedora and Windows. Any idea if the frequency can be changed either statically or dynamically by a programming solution?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you doing that requires manual configuration of per-core frequency scaling?